# PHP PDO MySQL password_verify issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, passwords

I am rebuilding login page now.

I have original one without password_verify code is working fine.

Original code without password_verify code:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

if($username != "" && $password != "") {

    try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `u_name`=:username and `u_pass`=:pass";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam('username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue('pass', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        $row   = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($count == 1 && !empty($row)) {
            $_SESSION['sess_user_id']   = $row['aID'];
            $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['u_name'];
            echo "home.php";
        } else {
            echo "invalid";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error : ".$e->getMessage();
    }


} else {
    echo "Both fields are required!";
}
```

But I edited and added password_verify code below to original one and it won't work.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST["password"];

if($username != "" && $password != "") {

    try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE u_name = :uname" );
    $stmt->execute(array(':uname' => $_POST['username']));
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(count($row)>0) {
            if (password_verify($password, $row['u_pass'])) {
                $_SESSION['sess_user_id']   = $row['aID'];
                $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['u_name'];
                echo "home.php";
            } else {
            echo "invalid";
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error : ".$e->getMessage();
        }

    } else {
    echo "Both fields are required!";
    }
}
```

I'm still beginner for PDO password_veryfy
I can't figure it out ....

Would you please tell me what is wrong / where to fix it?

I appreciated your help.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A reference example: [Authenticating a user using PDO and password_verify()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/password_hash). the code is more tidy and production friendly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchAll()` returns a 2-dimensional array. Since there can only be one row in the table for a user, just use `fetch()` like you did in your original code.

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row && password_verify($password, $row['u_pass'])) {
    $_SESSION['sess_user_id']   = $row['aID'];
    $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['u_name'];
    echo "home.php";
} else {
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you fetch `$row` in the new version with `fetchAll()`, it is an array of records, the row your after is the first record in the result.  So you need to check the first row in the result...

```
if(count($row)>0) {
    if (password_verify($password, $row[0]['u_pass'])) {
        $_SESSION['sess_user_id']   = $row[0]['aID'];
        $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row[0]['u_name'];
        echo "home.php";
    } else {
    echo "invalid";
    }
```

In the previous version you used `fetch()` which is the main difference here.